# Can truth of a single predicate be defined by another language that only shares that predicate?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I have been looking at Tarski's work and asked a question here:

[Can truth be defined by a 'same-level' language according to Tarski's undefinability theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842951/can-truth-be-defined-by-a-same-level-language-according-to-tarskis-undefinabi?noredirect=1#comment5882281_2842951)

I am trying to refine my question as follows: if a 'meta-language' L* is meta- only as far as one predicate is concerned, can the truth of that predicate in the lower language L be proven? Or is it essential that L* contains all of L (plus more), to prove the truth of something in L?

Comment: Not clear... you say "the truth of that predicate"; I think it must be "the truth-predicate".

Comment: I guess I mean the truth of one single statement, without having to prove the truth of the entire language L.

Comment: Truth of a *single* statement $S$ can be expressed without any met-language; just say $S$.

Comment: But then I’m missing something important. When would a meta-language be needed? Can’t every truth be expressed within L then?

Comment: also, @AndreasBlass wouldn't this run into trouble with a statement like the liar's paradox?

Comment: Truth of any *single* statement of $L$ can (trivially) be expressed in $L$. The general notion of truth for $L$-sentences cannot be expressed in $L$ (Tarski's theorem).  The liar paradox is essentially the proof of Tarski's theorem. A (fairly) general notion of truth is needed in order to produce the liar sentence  ("This sentence is false"), and that's why such a general notion of truth can't exist.