# Can all math be done with axioms of length 3 or less?

Tags: axioms, foundations

[1] Assume math can be done with unrestricted grammars (See [Are axioms in math equivalent to production rules in unrestricted grammars?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3630481/are-axioms-in-math-equivalent-to-production-rules-in-unrestricted-grammars/3630588?noredirect=1#comment7463434_3630588)).

Can the grammar rules be rewritten to contain at most 3 symbols?

Here's an example:

Suppose we have a grammar rule `abcd>efgh`.

We can rewrite that grammar rule with these grammar rules

`ab>i` `cd>j` `ij>k` `l>ef` `m>gh` `n>lm` `k>n`

[2] Now each rule has at most 4 symbols (including the `>` symbol).

[3] For each rule that has 2 symbols on one side, we could introduce a new bidirectional (`=`) rule. For example:

Rewrite `ab>c` as these two rules `d>c` `ab=d`

[4] Thus we can rewrite rules:

`n>i` `n=ab` `o>j` `o=cd` `p>k` `p=ij` `l>q` `q=ef` `m>r` `r=gh` `n>s` `s=lm` `k>n`

[5] We can omit the `>` and `=` symbols; the symbols can be inferred. It's always in position 2. We can infer `=` or `>` based on the number of symbols. If there are 2 symbols it's `>`. If there are 3 symbols it's `=`. We can write our rules as:

`ni` `nab` `oj` `ocd` `pk` `pij` `lq` `qef` `mr` `rgh` `ns` `slm` `kn`

[5] Therefore any unrestricted grammar can be rewritten as axioms with at most 3 symbols.

[6] **By [1] and [5], math is possible with axioms of length 3 or less.** (I have not proved the "meta-axioms" to be length 3 or less.)

**Is this right?**

There appears to be a polynomial overhead to do this:

[7] Suppose we have `n` total symbols in our axioms (total axiom length).

[8] Each axiom has `n` or less symbols.

[9] Each axiom can be expressed as a single `a>b` rule and 0 or more `a=bc` rules.

How many `a=bc` rules do we need per axiom?

[10] The `a=bc` rules can be created as a tree (one tree for each side of `a>b`):

(For simple arithmetic, assume `n` is a power of 2; `n=2^k`.)

[11] Each side of the tree will have at most `n` symbols.

```
log(n) + log(n/2) + log(n/4) + ... + log(1)
= log(n/2^0) + log(n/2^1) + log(n/2^2) + ... + log(n/^k)
= log(n) - log(2^0) + log(n) - log(2^1) + log(n) - log(2^2) + ... + log(n) - log(2^k)
= log(n^log(n)) - log(2^0) - log(2^1) - log(2^2) - ... - log(2^k)
= n - log(2^0) - log(2^1) - log(2^2) - ... - log(2^k)
<= n
```

[12] Therefore, to adding `a=bc` rules for one side of an `a>b` rule will create at most `log(n) + log(n/2) + log(n/4) + ... + log(1) <= n` additional rules.

[13] Therefore, in terms of `n`, the total axiom length, there is polynomial overhead to have max length of 3 per axiom.

Comment: Are we allowed arbitrarily many letters in the alphabet?

Comment: @MarkS. As many as you need

Answer (score 2):

If we allow infinitely many symbols and rules this is trivially doable. Pick your favorite formalization of a sufficiently rich system. We can recursively introduce additional symbols and $4$-symbol rules which reduce each string $\sigma$ in that formalization to a single symbol $c_\sigma$. Now for every valid deduction $\sigma\vdash\tau$ introduce a new rule $c_\sigma\leadsto c_\tau$.

If we want only finitely many symbols and rules, things are a bit more complicated but there's still a fairly boring solution. There are length-four-rule systems which are appropriately Turing complete, and so in a sense we can embed first-order logic into it (specifically, there is a computable way to assign a string $s_\varphi$ in the system to a first-order sentence $\varphi$ such that $s_\varphi\leadsto s_\psi$ iff $\varphi\vdash\psi$).

Comment: "If we allow infinitely many symbols" I don't think it's "infinite". Cutting down the max-length of any axiom may be tree-like/logarithmic (haven't worked out the formula)

Comment: "If we want only finitely many symbols and rules" The number of symbols you have is like the base; axioms are 3-digit natural numbers in that base; you could convert it to base-2 (or whatever finite base you want). So some sort of tree/logmarithic process.

Comment: What does the squiggly imply mean?

Comment: "we can embed first-order logic into it (specifically, there is a computable way to assign a string  in the system to a first-order sentence  such that ⇝ iff ⊢)." Does that imply first-order logic can do all of math?

Comment: (I've heard second order is more expressive, so clearly I'm misunderstanding)

Comment: @WordsLikeJared This is a common issue when first learning logic. The short version is that from a "formal foundations" point of view, the snappiest description of the situation is that mathematics takes place within the first-order theory ZFC. When we write arguments which look second-order (or otherwise beyond first-order), they're really proxies for first-order arguments within ZFC (whose language is rich enough to approximate second-order reasoning to a certain extent). The key point here is that first-order logic is "effective" in a precise sense: (continued)

Comment: the relation "$p$ is a proof of $\varphi$" is computable. By contrast, SOL *(at least, [with the standard semantics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#SemaSecoOrdeLogi) - if we use the Henkin semantics, it's just FOL in disguise)* is extremely far from computable in this sense, and so isn't actually usable. Meanwhile, FOL (unlike propositional logic) is Turing-complete in an appropriate sense, so is in fact rich enough to implement all the formal reasoning we can actually perform. So as long as "all of mathematics" means something computably-analyzable, FOL is good enough.

Comment: "the relation " is a proof of " is computable." Meaning "all formalized proofs are verifiable" ?

Comment: "Meanwhile, FOL (unlike propositional logic) is Turing-complete in an appropriate sense...FOL is good enough." Does that mean all math is equivalent to FOL?

Comment: @WordsLikeJared Yes. I can't computably tell whether a sentence is provable (if it's not I might search forever for a proof), but I can computably tell whether a purported proof is indeed a proof.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared "Does that mean all math is equivalent to FOL?" At some point you have to define what you mean by "all of math." As I said above, insofar as you grant the claim that mathematics takes place inside ZFC, then yes, that's true. (And this comment thread is getting rather long; I suggest any further questions be asked as new MSE questions.)