# Is FOL equivalent to Turing Machines?

Tags: first-order-logic, turing-machines

Does every FOL (axiom set expressible in First Order Logic) have a corresponding Turing machine?

The proved FOL statements would be strings the Turing machine accepts.

Does every Turing machine have a FOL?

The strings the Turing machine accepts are proved by a finite set of FOL axioms.

Someone said this:

> Meanwhile, FOL (unlike propositional logic) is Turing-complete in an appropriate sense

(See comments on https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635100/187128)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Turing himself showed that you can describe the behavior of any Turing-machine using FOL statements, and with that you can indeed show that any FOL statements a Turing-machine accepts would indeed be provable from a finite set of FOL axioms.

Going the other way around, for every finite set of FOL Axioms, you can construct a Turing machines that accepts all and only those statements provable from it.  This is closely related to Godel's Completeness Theorem: it turns out there is an algorithm that cranks out all and only valid FOL statements, and thus also a Turing-machine that can do that.