# Relative constructibility

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

In Jech's book Set Theory, the author defines *definable over a model*:

$$\text{def}_A(M) = \{X \subseteq M : X \text{ is definable over }(M,\epsilon,A \cap M)\},$$

where $A \cap M$ is considered a unary predicate. So let $X$ be a definable set over $(M,\epsilon,A \cap M)$; in other words, there exist a formula $\varphi$ and $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in M$ then there exists a formula $\varphi$ such that $X = \{x \in M : (M,\epsilon,A \cap M) \models \varphi(x,a_1, \ldots, a_n)\}$.

Does this mean that $a_i \in A \cap M$ for $I = 1, \ldots, n$? I am not sure what is the role the unary predicate $A \cap M$ plays in this definition. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It means that all the *parameters* $a_i$ are in $M$  They may or may not be in $A$. This is just as in ordinary constructibility, the special case of relative constructibility where $A = \emptyset$. Indeed, for any $A\in L$ we have $L[A] = L$. (Why?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an extra predicate you have in building the formulas. So for instance, $\varphi(x,a)$ could say $x\in a\land A(x)$ which is interpreted in $(M,\in, A\cap M)$ as meaning $x\in a\land x\in A\cap M,$ so e.g. this defines the set $X=(a\cap M)\cap (A\cap M).$

Comment: So, $\text{def}_A(M)$ is just $\text{def}(M)$ with an extra condition, i.e. $A(x)$, we can use when defining $\theta$?

Comment: @BobVance Yep, and with a bigger language you can (generally speaking) define more stuff, as Noah points out.

Answer (score 2):

No, the $a_i$s are not required to come from $A\cap M$. Rather, in $\mathsf{def}_A(M)$ the unary predicate naming ($M$'s intersection with) $A$ is **available for use in the definition $\varphi$**, similarly to how we use [individual elements as *parameters* in definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153993/what-is-a-definable-set/1154042#1154042).

For example, we **trivially** have the following:

> Suppose $(M;\in)$ is infinite. Then there is an $X\subseteq M$ which is not definable in $\mathcal{M}$; however, for every $X\subseteq M$ there is some $A\subseteq M$ such that $X\in\mathsf{def}_A(\mathcal{M})$.

The first result is just a counting argument; for the second result, take $A=X$ (or indeed $A=X\cup Y$ for any $Y$ disjoint from $M$) and $\varphi(x)\equiv A(x)$ (no $a_i$s are needed here at all).