# Kleene $\models^{x_1 x_2 ... x_n}$

Tags: predicate-logic

Mathematical Logic by Kleene page 107

[image]

As I understand for one variable $\forall x.A(x)$ it means that instead of considering all possible logical functions for $A(x)$ we need to choose only the function $I(x)=true$ for all values of $x$.

$A_1,...,A_m\models^{x_1...x_q}B \equiv \forall {x_1,...,x_q}.A_1,...\forall {x_1,...,x_q}.A_m \models B$ - if I got it right.

I see no difference between $\forall{x,y}.A(x,y)$ and $\forall{x}.A(x,y)$ because logical function $I(x,y)$ for $\forall{x}.A(x,y)$ always $true$ regardless of $y$ and the same holds for $\forall{x,y}.A(x,y)$

I can't get the difference between $A_1,...,A_m\models^{x_1...x_q}B$ and $A_1,...,A_m\models^{x_1...x_qx_{q+1}...x_r}B$

Comment: It should be clear that $\forall x,y.A(x,y)$ and $\forall x. A(x,y)$ *ought to* mean different things - for example, if $A(x,y)$ is $y\le x$, then $\forall x,y.A(x,y)$ should be false in $\mathbb{N}$ with $\le$ interpreted in the obvious way but $\forall x. A(x,y)$ will be *true* for one particular variable assignment (namely $y\mapsto 0$ or $y\mapsto 1$, depending on whether you consider $0$ a natural number). Keeping this in mind should help isolate the formal point of difference.

Comment: So $\forall x.A(x,y)$ means $\forall x\exists y.A(x,y)$

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that either. Both "$\forall x,y. A(x,y)$" and "$\forall x\exists y. A(x,y)$" are **sentences** (or **closed formulas**): their truth value is determined as soon as a model is specified. The truth value of the formula "$\forall x. A(x,y)$" is not in general determined by the model alone; we also need to know a variable assignment for $y$. Think of a formula with free variables as [defining a subset of (some Cartesian power of) the structure in question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153993/what-is-a-definable-set).

Comment: Kleene's old superscript-variable notation denotes *closure* of all *universal* quantifiers binding each superscript-variable applicable for each premise $A_i$, it's a little confusing but you should regard it as a closed formula by all applicable universal quantifiers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Model: $B=\{1,2,3\}, I(1,2)=I(2,1)=I(3,3)=I(3,1) = true$ other pairs are $false$, so $\forall x$ there $\exists y$. Could you please provide some examples for the difference between $∀x.A(x,y)$ and $∀x∃y.A(x,y)$?

Comment: If your $A(x,y)$ is $y≤x$, then we should have $I(1,1)=I(2,1)=I(3,1)=I(2,2)=I(3,2)=I(3,3)=true$ and other combos false to arrive at your conclusion $\forall x \exists y.A(x,y)$. As for $\forall x.A(x,y)$ it's an open formula with $y$ free as a parameter, so it hasn't any truth value. Kleene meant $\forall x \forall y.A(x,y)$ by default to close all superscript-variable as sentences...

Comment: In my understanding $A(x,y,z),\forall x.A(x,y,z),\forall x\forall y.A(x,y,z)$ are predicate variables each of them determines a set of logical functions that are applicable to them. How can I determine those sets to compere different forms of $A(x,y,z)$ (with or without quantifiers)? For example, consider $\forall x \forall y.A(x,y,z)$ form, whether the logical function that gives $true$ for every $y$ regardless of $x,z$ satisfies that form for $x,y,z\in\{0,1\}$ domain?