# Goedel's Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: logic, fixed-point-theorems

Let's consider an arithmetic theory such as Peano Arithmetic. Suppose the Gödel codes of all the **true** sentences are **even** and all the false sentences are odd. Then, how can there be a fixed point for the predicate, $\phi(x)=$"***x is odd**.*"?

Comment: "Suppose the Gödel codes of all the true sentences are even and all the false sentences are odd." This can't occur, pretty much for exactly the reason you describe - this is [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem). Not every seemingly-plausible property of Godel codings is actually realizable! (This raises the question of what exactly we mean by "Godel coding," and in fact we can give a precise if somewhat weird definition; basically, a Godel coding is a function from sentences to numbers satisfying a couple definability properties ...

Comment: The fixed point theorem is a consequence of these definability properties, and meanwhile no such function can map all true statements to even numbers and all false statements to odd numbers.)

Comment: Or, conversely, if we do take _some_ coding (which necessarily won't be a Gödel coding in @NoahSchweber's sense), then we'll have trouble doing things that we would want to be able to do with the coding, such as writing $\phi(x,n,t)={}$"the $n$th character of the statement coded by $x$ is the character coded by $t$" (in other words, word-processing operations)

Comment: We might as well ask, "suppose all the programs of halting (zero-input) algorithms end in 0, and all the programs of non-halting algorithms end in 1." (I'm referencing the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) here.) _Reading_ and executing those programs becomes an uncomputable task.

Answer (score 3):

Turning my comments into an answer, the issue is that when you write

> Suppose the Gödel codes of all the true sentences are even and all the false sentences are odd

you're making a very false assumption: that that situation can in fact occur with respect to a Godel coding system. In fact, the rest of your question is more-or-less the proof that this can't happen! Keep in mind that the diagonal lemma is not trivial; it doesn't apply to *all* functions from formulas to numbers, only to *some*. So the fact that this places restrictions on the possible behaviors shouldn't be a surprise.

---

Specifically, we have the following result:

> **([Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem))** Suppose $\mathscr{F}$ is an injective function from formulas to numbers such that the "substitution relation" $$\mathfrak{S}:=\{(l,m,n)\in\mathbb{N}^3: l\in ran(\mathscr{F})\wedge \mathscr{F}(\mathscr{F}^{-1}(l)[\underline{m}/x])=n\}$$ is definable in $\mathcal{N}$. Then $\mathscr{F}[Th(\mathcal{N})]$ is **not** definable in $\mathcal{N}$.

That's a lot of notation! Here's what it means:

- "Formula" means "first-order formula in the language of arithmetic," and "number" means "natural number."
- $\underline{n}$ is the **numeral** corresponding to $n$, e.g. $\underline{3}=(1+1)+1$.
- $\varphi[t/x]$ is the formula gotten from $\varphi$ by replacing all free occurrences of the variable $x$ with the term $t$.

So intuitively, $\mathfrak{S}(l,m,n)$ means "If we take the formula with code $l$ and substitute $m$ for the variable $x$, the resulting formula has code $n$." And it's not hard to see that we really lean on the definability of $\mathfrak{S}$ in proving the diagonal lemma for $\mathscr{F}$, when in fact $\mathscr{F}$ is a "reasonable coding system," so this matters.

Continuing on:

- "Definable" [means what it usually does in model theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153993/what-is-a-definable-set/1154042#1154042).
- $\mathcal{N}$ is the structure $(\mathbb{N};+,\times,0,1)$ (or anything "morally equivalent" to that).
- $\mathscr{F}[Th(\mathcal{N})]$ is the image under $\mathscr{F}$ of the theory of $\mathcal{N}$; or, more intuitively, the set of **$\mathscr{F}$-codes of true sentences**.

Comment: A lot of Gödel's stuff is basically just about word processors, because checking whether a proof is valid is essentially a word processing task. First (_arithmetization_) you show that the arithmetic theory can represent word processing stuff, and second (_diagonalization_) you do [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%27s_paradox)-esque stuff to write a sentence that refers to its own provability. (In one proof, anyway.)