# Can the notion of "intensional definitions" be captured in terms of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

It's easy to see how an extensional definition is just the elements of a set, but what about the notions of descriptions of the properties, axioms, and rules that can be used to define a set?

Comment: The notion of a **definable set**, and the connection between a particular formula and the set it defines (in a given structure), is a relevant one; are you already familiar with this? (If not, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153993/what-is-a-definable-set/1154042#1154042).)

Comment: This starts getting you into mathematical logic. In addition to Noah's reference on definable sets, you might also be interested in a result like Beth's definability theorem.

Comment: Thank you! @NoahSchweber Did you write that book yet? ;)